# Android: Keyboard event handler

Tags: android, keyboard-events

I created a full-screen application and set the default orientation to landscape. When I open the keyboard the application crashes therefore I would like to override the method which executes on keyboard slide. Does anyone know which method is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case sliding the keyboard triggers this event

```
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);        
    }
```

and for more information on handling screen orientation changes [read this article](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/40792/1954).